# How does one say "Five cubic metres"?

Tags: phrase-request, numbers

I found myself on the telephone today attempting to explain the volume that a bunch of furniture would perhaps occupy in a truck, and I used

> Fünf cubisch Metern

But it was fairly clear to me that I was making a mistake.  How does one state such measurements correctly in German?

Comment: *Fünf Kubikmeter*

Comment: @Em1 Thanks.  Post as answer?

Comment: Great question, a new and useful topic, +1.

Comment: Hint: Meter and Kubikmeter are both singular and plural. Ein Meter, fünf Meter, ein Kubikmeter, fünf Kubikmeter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The measurement for volume is given in *Kubikmeter* <sup>[DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kubikmeter) [WIKIPEDIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubikmeter)</sup>

> Dagegen sagte der ukrainische Energieminister Juri Boiko in Kiew, Gazprom pumpe jeden Tag 75 Millionen Kubikmeter weniger Gas in die Pipelines durch die Ukraine als vereinbart. <sup>[ZEIT](http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2012-02/russland-gas-winter)</sup>
>
> Das Mädchen aus dem brandenburgischen Plattenburg war an jenem Tag an der Steilküste verunglückt, als sich mehrere Tausend Kubikmeter Erde und Kreide aus dem Kliff lösten und in die Tiefe stürzten. <sup>[ZEIT](http://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/zeitgeschehen/2012-01/ruegen-maedchen-leiche-kueste)</sup>

Mathematical hint: One *Kubikdezimeter* is one *Liter* or 1000 Liter are one *Kubikmeter* ;p

Comment: Hint: Between 1901 and 1964 one litre was not defined to be exactly 1 cubic decimetre  cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre orhttp://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liter. I had to learn that garbage (the definition of 1901) when I went to school.

Comment: Pronounciation: Kub'ikmeter (stress on the i)

Answer (score 4):

Neben *Kubikmeter* kann man auch sagen *Meter hoch Drei*, was die Lesart für *m³* ist, und in mathematischen/technischen Zusammenhängen üblich ist.

---

Beside *Kubikmeter* you could as well use *Meter hoch Drei*, especially in mathematical/technical kontext, and which is just the pronunciation¹ of *m³*.

¹) Thanks to Em1 after longer debate in comments, he convinced me, that it is better than `articulation` or `spelling`.

Comment: [_Spelling_](http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=spelling) is not what you mean. I'm not sure how to say it correctly.

Comment: `Articulation`?

Comment: @userunknown This was also my first idea. But no, I don't think so. Pronunciation is more appropriate. [Articulation](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/articulation) [Pronunciation](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/pronunciation)

Comment: Maybe this would be a question worth on GLU :D

Comment: @Em1: I decided for `articulation` after reading your dictionary links. It would be a good question for EL&U, not GL&U - since an expert for the German language needn't know it. In expert for the English language should.

Comment: @userunknown Darn. Of course ELU :D Es ist doch noch so früh... Ich werd' mir mal weiter Gedanken drüber machen und vllt der Tage auf ELU fragen.

Comment: @userunknown I'm pretty sure pronunciation is correct: [Pronunciation of mathematical symbols](http://www.uefap.com/speaking/symbols/symbols.htm). The first sentence use the word *pronunciation* and cm^3 is listed. And [another source](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/math/ms_graduate/resources/SayingMath.pdf) (and I find many more)

Comment: @Em1: Enough! Convinced. :)

Answer (score 4):

Specific for the trade with wood (esp. firewood or other cut wood), there is also the [*Raummeter* or *Ster*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raummeter). One *Ster* includes the space between the pieces of wood. Depending how you stack the wood, the result may differ.

In your specific case (furniture), *Ster* would be wrong (at least, if you don’t want to use it as firewood)

Comment: While we are at it: `Raummeter` is also known as `Festmeter`

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that, while everyone learns about the unit Kubikmeter rather early in school, knowledge about the units Raummeter or Ster may be restricted to professionals of wood/furniture-related industries.